# Make SSL certificate trusted in browser via SSL Bump Squid

Tags: openssl, ssl, squid, https

my goal is to insert custom HTML injections in HTTPS pages.

I've setup Squid with SSL Bump. I generated a self signed certificate. With this setup I'm getting client side warnings that the certificate was signed by an unknown authority.

I have another valid certificate for my web site. I tried to make Squid work with this certificate, but get another issue. The chain of certificate is not valid.

It's looking like ROOT Certificate (valid) -> Company that gave me certificate (Not valid, chain error) -> My company (not valid) -> this site (not valid)

How can I make the last certificate valid on the client side?

I found that I can generate root a certificate and move it to the user on the client side. And import into their browser. But I have a lot of clients and I can't do it on each one.